# How to inject data from db in each templates django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have to inject contacts in footer in each my templates. I thought use my own context processor, but I don't know whether to access the database from context processors and join it with context from view.
Will you help me?
P.S.: in Laravel (blade) for this exist builtin function @inject

Comment: can you provide the code you tried? and what do you exactly mean by injecting contacts? you need to get some data from database and render it in template?

Comment: Why do you need to hit db for contact info? Anyway just use template inheritance and add contact info into a base template. If you add it to context processor, it will be available in every view.

Comment: yep, I can add contacts to base template, but I don't know how select them from db. I have to select them from each view in order to have access to them in base template?